# Interpreting an apparent inconsistency - fitting regression models on subsets suggested by an interaction

Tags: regression, modeling, interaction

Say we learn a linear regression model with three continuous predictors $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ (along with interaction terms $X_1X_3$ and $X_2X_3$), for some variable Y.

The fitted model suggests a significant interaction effect such that, for some threshold $\epsilon$:

if $X_3 < \epsilon$ then $\beta_{X_1} > \beta_{X_2}$,

but if $X_3$ > $\epsilon$, then $\beta_{X_1} < \beta_{X_2}$.

However, if the model is fit again, this time only on the subset of the data where $X_3$ > $\epsilon$, this model has $\beta_{X_1}$ > $\beta_{X_2}$.

On the surface, this seems to be a contradiction. Under what circumstances could this behavior arise, and how might it be interpreted?